# Make div same as normal text using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make my website responsive,

When the width is less than 1024px, I need to add the div menu-item to the menu.

I need to use this when the width is more than 1024px

```
<div id="menu" >
    HOME
    TOP40
    DJS
        <div id="br"></div>
    SHOUTBOX
    VERZOEKJES
</div>
```

And when the width is less than 1024px, I need to use this

```
<div id="menu" >
    <div id="menu-item">HOME</div>
    <div id="menu-item">TOP40</div>
    <div id="menu-item">DJS</div>
        <div id="br"></div>
    <div id="menu-item">SHOUTBOX</div>
    <div id="menu-item">VERZOEKJES</div>
</div>
```

So when the width of the screen is more than 1024px, I want to make the #menu-item
the same as text, I already tried float: left; but that wasn't working.

Sorry, I don't know what kind of code's you need so
Live demo is at random-radio.net

Comment: You shouldn't put the same id on five different elements.

Comment: Already found solution, because I may not answer my own, I posted it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/PXrUMtPq

Comment: Post an answer here and mark it as accepted than.

Comment: He says, Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on CSS media queries, here's a good article: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/